# How to add the Wrap Text to google slide shapes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm trying to **Wrap text in Google Slide Shape** using Google Script

Sample Code:

```
function wrapText(){
    var slide=SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[4]
    var shape = slide.getShapes()[0];

    shape.wrapText();
}
```

Above code, I tried to access the **Google Slide** [slideNumber 4], from this slide accessing the *Shape 0 which is having some text* & I need to wrap this text.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the `wrapText()` method from but Google Apps Script doesn't have a method called wrapText() for any of its applications. https://developers.google.com/s/results/?q=%22wrapText%22&p=%2Fapps-script%2F Sadly this is something that may have to be done manually, programmatically, as `Shape[]` objects do not have a `wrapText()` method that can be called. What are you wanting to wrap the text around?

Comment: I am trying to write something to shape, and it's overflowing due to shape size. I want the shape to re-sized based on text length.

Comment: Unfortunately Text wrapping for shapes in for extending Google Slides with Apps Script isn't possible programmatically via an endpoint or method call. Have you tried changing the font size in the shape proportionally to the shape's dimensions? That way you could change the font wrapping on shape size edit?